# Regex match pattern with specific disqualifier

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I have a regex that will remove .php from the end of a URL:

`^(.*)\.php$`

this will match www.mysite.com/something.php with the first capturing group being www.mysite.com/something

I want to tweak this to match all urls like this a excluding specific url path. For instance "exclude.php" should not be matched and thus leave the .php

`www.mysite.com/exclude.php` -> `www.mysite.com/exclude.php`

but for any other path it should remove it:

`www.mysite.com/anythingelse.php` -> `www.mysite.com/anythingelse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind for excluding a text before `.php`:

```
^(.+)(?<!\/exclude)\.php$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mUf301/2)

`(?<!\/exclude)` is negative lookbehind to assert failure if `.php` is preceded by `/exclude`